# Error Compling Contract

Tags: ink, wasm, astar

I am just starting with wasm and ink.

I have installed the following dependency:

`npm install -g @astar-network/swanky-cli`

I am trying to compile the contract flipper and I get the following warnings and error:

```
swanky contract compile flipper
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 10.2.1      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-core\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\cjs
        cjs 10.2.1      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@polkadot\keyring\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\cjs
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 10.2.1      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@polkadot\util\cjs
        cjs 10.2.6      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\node_modules\@polkadot\util\cjs
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 10.2.1      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-core\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\cjs
        cjs 10.2.1      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@polkadot\keyring\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\cjs
        cjs 10.2.6      node_modules\@astar-network\swanky-cli\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\cjs
✖ Error Compiling contract
```

How do I fix the warnings and the error?

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning by polkadotjs library, and shouldn't affect the compilation.

To get rid of the warning, I suggest installing Swanky the recommended way, by downloading the prebuilt release from Github.
If the warning persist, you can run it in an isolated environment, like nix shell or a dev container. (We'll soon have an official one too)

To find out what is really breaking your compilation, run the `swanky contract compile` command with `-v` flag.

Comment: There seems to be problems with running swanky installed this way since v.1.0.9 at least for me: `swanky-v1.0.9/dist/commands/init/index.js: Cannot find module 'tslib'`

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with the packager that caused issues in 1.0.9. Please use a newer version that fixes it.

Comment: Just to let you know the same problem exists in v1.0.10 - the newest release up to date.

Comment: thanks for the report, we're checking it out.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply. I use a windows environment.
I do run the command:

> swanky contract compile test -v

(test is the contract folder name).
But I only get the error: ✖ Error Compiling contract and not more.

There are two ways I try to compile a contract:

> swanky init test (create flipper template)

> swanky contract compile flipper -v

and

> cargo contract new test

> swanky contract compile test -v

for both I get the same error.

Comment: This is not actually an answer, please use comments on the question to clarify and/or update the original question.

Comment: Please let me know as follwing. 1. swanky --version 2. node --version 3. yarn --version 4. Whether have you set "git config" 5. OS version

Comment: 1. swanky --version: @astar-network/swanky-cli/1.0.7 win32-x64 node-v18.13.0 2. node --version: v18.13.0 3. yarn --version: 1.22.10 4. Windows 10 Home 22H2

Comment: Can you use wsl ubutsu 20.04?